# Can't read jsonfile in python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read a jsonfile but it isn't working, but I can write to the jsonfile.

```
    with open('Account.json', 'r') as inputFile:
        data = json.load(inputFile)


    with open('Account.json', 'w') as saveFile:
        json.dump(Names, saveFile, indent=2)
```

So, I dumped the nested dictionary inside the jsonfile. I can write everything, but when I'm trying to read the I get the error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The data inside the jsonfile:

```
Names = {
  "1": {
    "e-mail": "test"
  },
  "2": {
    "e-mail": "test1"
  },
  "3": {
    "e-mail": "test2"
  },
  "4": {
    "e-mail": "test3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a valid json file. A valid json file starts with `{` and ends with `}`. When I have issues with JSON files I usually start by running them through a validator, like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. That tends to make finding the issue very easy.

Comment: I started with a curly bracket and closed it also?

Comment: The `Names = ` bit has to go

Comment: Having an object (with curly brackets) as the outermost structure is only one of the valid options for JSON. But still the assignment does not belong there.

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen a JSON document before that has an array as the outermost structure, but apparently that's valid as well.